# многоуровневое заполнение treeview из БД

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных, winforms, рекурсия

есть 4 таблицы, связанные в порядке подчиненности, пытаюсь создать дерево из их содержимого.

```
 using System;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Windows.Forms;
 using System.Data.SqlClient;
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    private TreeView tree;
    public Form3()
    {
        this.tree = new TreeView();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        this.tree.ImageIndex = -1;
        this.tree.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(8, 8);
        this.tree.Name = "tree";
        this.tree.SelectedImageIndex = -1;
        this.tree.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(276, 248);
        this.tree.TabIndex = 0;
        this.AutoScaleBaseSize = new System.Drawing.Size(5, 14);
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(292, 266);
        this.Controls.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.Control[] { this.tree });
        this.Text = "Hierarchical TreeView";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form3_Load);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

        InitializeComponent();
    }
    string connectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=bdsi;Integrated Security=SSPI";
    string macroSQL = "SELECT * FROM ВыборМакроОбъект";
    string superSQL = "SELECT * FROM ВыборСуперОбъект";


    private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(macroSQL, con);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        con.Open();
        adapter.Fill(ds, "ВыборМакроОбъект");
        adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = superSQL;
        adapter.Fill(ds, "ВыборСуперОбъект");
        adapter.Fill(ds, "ВыборОбъект");

        con.Close();

        DataColumn parentCol = ds.Tables["ВыборМакроОбъект"].Columns["МакроКод"];
        DataColumn childCol = ds.Tables["ВыборСуперОбъект"].Columns["макрообъект"];
        DataRelation relation = new DataRelation("макрообъект", parentCol, childCol);
        ds.Relations.Add(relation);

        foreach (DataRow parent in ds.Tables["ВыборМакроОбъект"].Rows)
        {
            TreeNode nodeParent = tree.Nodes.Add(parent["макрообъект"].ToString());
            foreach (DataRow child in parent.GetChildRows(relation))
            {
                nodeParent.Nodes.Add(child["суперобъект"].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Подскажите как добавить остальные две таблицы, уже третий день голову ломаю, перерыл кучу форумов но ничего стоящего не нашел.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

мне нужно чтобы было что то вроде

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

само собой что вместо цифр должны быть данные из таблиц, 0 - ВыборМакроОбъект, 1- ВыборСуперОбъект, - 2 ВыборОбъект, 3 - Позиция, нужно дерево из данных

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ВыборМакроОбъект]( [МакроКод] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, [макрообъект] [nvarchar](255) NULL, CONSTRAINT [ВыборМакроОбъект$PrimaryKey] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [МакроКод] ASC )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY] ) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ВыборСуперОбъект]( [СуперКод] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, [суперобъект] [nvarchar](255) NULL, [макрообъект] [int] NULL, CONSTRAINT [ВыборСуперОбъект$PrimaryKey] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [СуперКод] ASC )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY] ) ON [PRIMARY] 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ВыборОбъект]( [ОбъектКод] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, [объект] [nvarchar](100) NULL, [суперобъект] [int] NULL, CONSTRAINT [ВыборОбъект$PrimaryKey] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [ОбъектКод] ASC )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY] ) ON [PRIMARY] 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ВыборПозиция]( [объект] [int] NULL, [позиция СИ] [nvarchar](255) NULL, [НПИ] [nvarchar](255) NULL, [интерфейс] [nvarchar](255) NULL, [ВПИ] [nvarchar](255) NULL, [тип СИ] [nvarchar](255) NULL, [вид МО] [nvarchar](255) NULL, [Код] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, [измеряемый параметр] [nvarchar](255) NULL, [единица измерения] [nvarchar](255) NULL, CONSTRAINT [ВыборПозиция$Код1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [Код] ASC )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY] ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128269/discussion-on-question-by----treeview--).

Comment: Загляните в чат.